# R - Function that call conditionally another functions

Tags: r, function, igraph

I am working with `igraph` package and I'm trying to build a function that calculates the number of intra-community edges of different algorithm implementation. I try to concatenate everything inside the function even the algorithms community detection functions. Like this:

```
library("igraph")

intra.edges<-function(G,algorithm) {
  if(algorithm==1){
    Mod<-cluster_louvain(G)}
  if(algoritmo==2){
    Mod<-cluster_edge_betweenness(G)}
  if(algoritmo==3){
    Mod<-cluster_walktrap(G)}

Com<-as.data.frame(sizes(Mod))
NoCom<-as.vector(Com$Community.sizes)
vert<-NULL
  for(i in 1:length(NoCom)){
    M<-which(membership(Mod)==i)
    sg<-induced.subgraph(G,M)
    c.ec<-ecount(sg)
    vert<-c.ec
  }
  intra<-data.frame(Com,vert)
  print(intra)
}
```

When I try the function, it don't works correctly. For example:

When I run:

```
G <- graph.famous("Zachary")
intra.edges(G,1)
```

I get:

```
Community.sizes     Freq    vert
      1              9       6
      2              7       6
      3              9       6
      4              4       6
      5              5       6
```

And when I run `intra.edges(G,2)` or `intra.edges(G,3)` I get the same output.

Also, not all the network's components have six vertex, it is only in one component.

Comment: You're using `<-` to test for equality within your function. You should use `==`. `<-` is the assignment operator.

Comment: @dash2 You're right, but in the column `vert`  I continue getting the same values. Thanks!

Comment: You're assigning to `vert` several times in the loop. Every time it overwrites the previous assignment. You might want something like `vert[i] <- c.ec`. I suspect you may need to learn some R basics before doing this stuff, though.

Comment: You need to be adding your vert value to the data.frame with each iteration in your for loop.  As it is, you are creating a data.frame using `Com` and the last value given to `vert`.  In this case, it is apparently 6.  When you create `intra`, `vert is recycled to create your data.frame

Comment: @dash2 You're right again! Thanks!!!

Comment: as an aside, there appears to be no reason to create the object `c.ec`.  You can just directly assign the result to `vert`, saving space in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add your calculated value of `vert` to the dataframe with each iteration of your for loop by changing your code to:

```
intra<-Com
  for(i in 1:length(NoCom)){
    M<-which(membership(Mod)==i)
    sg<-induced.subgraph(G,M)
    intra$vert[i]<-ecount(sg)
  }
print(intra)
```

Or, as @dash2 suggested, create a vector called `vert` and add values sequentially like this:

```
vert<-NULL
  for(i in 1:length(NoCom)){
    M<-which(membership(Mod)==i)
    sg<-induced.subgraph(G,M)
    c.ec<-ecount(sg)
    vert[i]<-c.ec
  }
```